# In flutter How I can Show interstial ads after each 5 minutes

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

i have a problem implementing interstitial timed ads with flutter. i have implemented one option which shows ads when a button is clicked but i want to implement where it shows ad every 5 minutes what Should I Do Can any Help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Timer.periodic`

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (_) {
  // show popup from here
});
```